# best practice for <img> null alt attribute where alt="" isn't technically possible

Tags: html, accessibility, visualforce

I have an image that is purely decorative—the meaningful content for its section of the page is provided by header and sub-header text, and I have no need to highlight the image to assistive software.

In general, the best practice for this from an accessibility POV is a null alt attribute:

`<img src="human_unfriendly_filename.jpg" alt=""/>`

However, SalesForce's Visualforce templating system strips blank tags out of the source entirely, so the above results in

`<img src="human_unfriendly_filename.jpg">`

being rendered on the live page.

This is very bad from an accessibility POV, as assistive software will likely default to the image filename. Our SalesForce implementation partner has suggested `alt="image"`, but this is still flagged by our accessibility software, and is explicitly called out as [a bad example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Accessibility_concerns) in the `<img>` element reference (albeit in a somewhat different context).

Is there a better approach? Visualforce also strips `alt` (attribute with no value), and [`alt="null"` is apparently discouraged](https://knowbility.org/blog/2019/an-alt-text-primer/). I'd imagine this only comes up in a narrow set of circumstances, but could an `alt` value with descriptive text of the image be more appropriate here? Or some other solution? Changing the filename?

I have some time with our a11y consultant booked soon, so I'll report back with their response as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following attributes : `aria-hidden="true"` `role=none` or `role=presentation`

Comment: this was most of the solution the a11y consultant very tentatively recommended with an ``alt="terse description"`` included as a fallback (though it's weird to have both). I'll elucidate when I get around to answering more fully.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an image use an empty div with appropriate dimensions and image as a background of a div.

Comment: Not a bad idea—the live instance is slightly more complicated than the example (within ```<picture>```) but wouldn't be too hard to recreate as you're suggesting using CSS ```background-image``` and ```@media()```.

Answer (score 0):

After a call with our a11y consultant—who was quite bemused by Visualforce's quirks—this is what we decided on:

`<img src="human_unfriendly_filename.jpg" alt="terse description" aria-hidden="true"/>`

Technically, it's not great practice to have a non-null `alt` and `aria-hidden` on the same image (why would you both describe and hide it?) and might still trigger errors. But it worked as intended (image ignored) in all the readers we tested, and in the event that one does decide to read the `alt`, its 1-2 words should be minimally obtrusive.

He offered some pushback against further specification with `role` as it might just look like throwing spaghetti at the wall (my interpretation of his words), and on a broader level stressed the importance of documenting the underling rationale somewhere (commit comments), just in case someone tries use the non-standard approach as evidence of a11y carelessness in legal proceeding.

Finally, while moving from `<img>` to `background-image` was indeed the "cleanest" fix, its likely this code pattern will be used at some point for an image that contains user-relevant information, and thus require the ability to provide a non-null `alt` value.